# Please make approved edits visible to both the editor and the approver

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Back before I achieved my lifelong goal of 2000 rep on SO, when I made an edit to a post, I could still see the edited version before it was officially approved. This was nice. Especially with code dumps like this: [Crash log analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332662/crash-log-analysis). It made an otherwise unintelligible post suddenly readable.

Now that I have over 2000 rep and all the responsibilities that come with my new found editing power, I can approve (or disapprove) edits of aspiring SO users. Usually I approve. Especially in code dump cases. Sadly, my new powers are limited and it takes 2 approval votes for the suggested edits to come through. Meanwhile, after I approve a much needed edit that I would otherwise have done myself (but who I am to deny the aspiring editor his 2 points?), I have to look at the garbled mess of a question. Yuck.

May we please get to see the question as edited once we approve the edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always click Improve in this case.

As far as I know, this still awards the 2 rep to the editor.

Comment: Interesting way to skirt the problem. Thanks for this.

Comment: @PengOne Looks like that won't do anymore. `Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because: •You seem to be improving a post however, you made no changes`.

Comment: Yes, I realized that a couple of days ago. Now I just make a silly change. Rather pointless, really. Oh well.